# Formating a string based on a list value

Tags: c#, json

I am working in C# on a small program for PoE. Everything is working like it should except for one thing:

I am working with a json file, here is the part i need help with:

```
"sockets": [{
                "group": 0,
                "attr": "I",
                "sColour": "B"
            }, {
                "group": 0,
                "attr": "D",
                "sColour": "G"
            }, {
                "group": 1,
                "attr": "D",
                "sColour": "G"
            }
        ]
```

Translated to the desired result, this part of my code need to return: B-G G 
sColour with the same group need to be linked by an hyphen. 
sColour with a different group are not linked with an hyphen. 

I tried using StringBuilder with append, tried "string +=", tried foreach and for loops... 
I just can't find a logic to return what i want with the data i have in the json.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
public static void GenItemText()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles("tmp","*.txt");
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            File.Delete(f);
        }
        Stash j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stash>(File.ReadAllText("stash.json"));
        List<string> prop = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in j.Items)
        {
            if (i.Name != "")
            {
                prop.Add("Rarity: Rare");
                prop.Add($"{i.Name}");
                prop.Add($"{i.TypeLine}");
                prop.Add("--------");
                if (i.Properties != null && i.Properties.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var p in i.Properties)
                    {
                        if (p.Name == "Quality")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Quality: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Armour")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Armour: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Energy Shield")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Energy Shield: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Evasion Rating")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Evasion Rating: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Values.Count() == 0)
                        {
                            prop.Add($"{p.Name}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Physical Damage")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Physical Damage: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Elemental Damage")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Elemental Damage: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Critical Strike Chance")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Critical Strike Chance: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Attacks per Second")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Attacks per Second: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (p.Name == "Weapon Range")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Weapon Range: {p.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                    }
                    prop.Add("--------");
                }
                prop.Add("Requirements:");
                if (i.Requirements != null)
                {
                    foreach (var r in i.Requirements)
                    {
                        if (r.Name == "Level")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Level: {r.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (r.Name == "Str")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Str: {r.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (r.Name == "Dex")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Dex: {r.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                        if (r.Name == "Int")
                        {
                            prop.Add($"Int: {r.Values[0][0].String}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                prop.Add("--------");
                if (i.Sockets != null)
                {
                    // don't know what to do here, tried all i could think about...
                }

                msg.CMW($"{i.Name} - {i.TypeLine}",true,1);
                File.WriteAllLines($@"tmp\{i.Id}.txt", prop);
                prop.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want someone to code it for me, i just need hints, thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** 
I found a perfectly working solution, here is the code:

```
if (i.Sockets != null)
                {
                    List<string> g0 = new List<string>();
                    List<string> g1 = new List<string>();
                    List<string> g2 = new List<string>();
                    List<string> g3 = new List<string>();
                    List<string> g4 = new List<string>();
                    List<string> g5 = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var s in i.Sockets)
                    {
                        if (s.Group == 0)
                        {
                            g0.Add(s.SColour.ToString());
                        }
                        if (s.Group == 1)
                        {
                            g1.Add(s.SColour.ToString());
                        }
                        if (s.Group == 2)
                        {
                            g2.Add(s.SColour.ToString());
                        }
                        if (s.Group == 3)
                        {
                            g3.Add(s.SColour.ToString());
                        }
                        if (s.Group == 4)
                        {
                            g4.Add(s.SColour.ToString());
                        }
                        if (s.Group == 5)
                        {
                            g5.Add(s.SColour.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    string g0f = string.Join("-", g0);
                    string g1f = string.Join("-", g1);
                    string g2f = string.Join("-", g2);
                    string g3f = string.Join("-", g3);
                    string g4f = string.Join("-", g4);
                    string g5f = string.Join("-", g5);
                    prop.Add($"{g0f} {g1f} {g2f} {g3f} {g4f} {g5f}");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using CHOETL json reader(from nuggets).
What you need from there is read the JSON and use a dynamic "foreach item". If item.group == 0, then save the values to a list or a string getting item.sColour then format it as you want.

Here's is the guide: https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoETL

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave me just the right hint to help me find the perfect solution! I will post the code of my working solution in my OP.